# Chapter epigraph in the previous odd page

Tags: double-sided, books, epigraphs, single-sided

I'd like to insert an epigraph that comes with a chapter in the previous blank page, say in the odd page at the left of the chapter title.

[image: LibreOffice example of the desired result.]

A possible (naive) solution would be to put the epigraph in the previous chapter file, but since I am producing two different output files (both oneside and twoside books) I am worried this solution won't be feasible.

Many thanks!

Comment: Errata corrige. I meant the odd, not even.

Comment: You can edit the question....

Comment: ... and also add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer is given in the `epigraph` package's documentation (`> texdoc epigraph` section 2.4)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]
\cleartoevenpage
\pagestyle{plain} % or empty to remove first chapter's header is desired
\epigraph{A wonderful quotation}{Anonymous}
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

In a `twoside` document the `\chapter` macro calls `\cleardoublepage` so that it starts at the top of an odd page. The `\cleartoevenpage` macro goes to the next even page (where
you can put your epigraph) and then `\chapter` starts on the following odd page.

In a `oneside` document use `\clearpage` instead of `\cleartoevenpage`.

Comment: @picfra Are you going to accept my answer which, as far as I can tell, answers your question?

Comment: Sorry, I miss the notification email.
The answer you kindly provided works perfectly! Thank you!